# recompose withStateHandlers and TypeScript, implementation type leaks to component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped, recompose

I am trying to wrap a stateless functional component with `withStateHandlers` from recompose. I'm finding the only way I can do this is if I tweak my SFC's props to match some aspects of `withStateHandlers` that "leaks" out. Am I doing something wrong or is this a deficiency in recompose's types?

My SFC:

```
interface IProps {
    className?: string;
    isEditing: boolean;
    toggleEditing: () => void;
}

const MyComponent: React.SFC<IProps> = ({ className, isEditing, toggleEditing }) => (
    <button className={className} onClick={toggleEditing}>{isEditing ? 'stop editing' : 'start editing'}</button>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

From here, I want to wrap it with `withStateHandlers`:

```
import { withStateHandlers, StateHandlerMap, StateHandler } from 'recompose';
import MyComponent from '../components/myComponent';
interface IProps {
    className?: string;
}

interface IToggleEditingState {
    isEditing: boolean;
}

interface IToggleEditingStateUpdaters extends StateHandlerMap<IToggleEditingState> {
    toggleEditing: StateHandler<IToggleEditingState>
}

const withToggleEditState = withStateHandlers<IToggleEditingState, IToggleEditingStateUpdaters, IProps> (
    { isEditing: false },
    {
        toggleEditing: (state) => () => ({ isEditing: !state.isEditing })
    }
);

const StatefulMyComponent = withToggleEditState(MyComponent);
```

But this doesn't work, I get this error at compile time:

```
(32,43): Argument of type 'StatelessComponent<IProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<IProps & IToggleEditingState & IToggleEditingStateUpdaters>'.
  Type 'StatelessComponent<IProps>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<IProps & IToggleEditingState & IToggleEditingStateUpdaters>'.
    Type 'IProps' is not assignable to type 'IProps & IToggleEditingState & IToggleEditingStateUpdaters'.
      Type 'IProps' is not assignable to type 'IToggleEditingStateUpdaters'.
        Types of property 'toggleEditing' are incompatible.
          Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'StateHandler<IToggleEditingState>'.
            Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Partial<IToggleEditingState> | undefined'.
```

This is due to `toggleEditing` being defined as `() => void` in MyComponent's props. I fix that, and also get an error about a missing indexer.

To get the compiler happy, I need to change `MyComponent`'s IProps to be:

```
interface IProps {
    className?: string;
    isEditing: boolean;
    toggleEditing: (...payload: any[]) => any;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

I have to change `toggleEditing` to match the type of a `StateHandler<T>` as defined in @types/recompose. I also need to add the indexer. This looks to be because in @types/recompose, `withStateHandlers` returns an `InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TOutter & TState &TUpdates, TOutter>`, which ultimately after you walk your way through all the types, still expects an indexer on the component.

I noticed in the [tests](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/recompose/recompose-tests.tsx#L261), they are defining the SFC and then wrapping it all in one place. So the fact that the SFC actually has the odd prop requirements isn't apparent. I would like to define my SFC on its own, so I can reuse it in other situations. Am I just moving beyond the expected use case? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One mystery solved, I believe `(...payload: any[]) => object` is the correct type for `toggleEdit` as the main recompose docks say: "Passes state object properties and immutable updater functions in a form of (...payload: any[]) => Object to the base component."

So that just leaves the indexer.